# How can I pull in changes to a file from a subdirectory in another git repository

Tags: git

I have a file in my git repository which sometimes receives bug fixes in another git repository. I would like to be able to pull those commits into my repo.

For example:

```
project_a/
  /.git
  /src/somefile.cpp

project_b/
  /.git
  /utils/converters/apples/bananas/src/somefile.cpp
```

I would like to pull in commits from `project_b` to `project_a` for `somefile.cpp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `project_b` as a remote and then fetch and cherry-pick from it. Try something like this:

```
git remote add project_b /path/to/project_b/
git fetch project_b
```

Now you can cherry pick from `project_b`. If the commit you want is at the tip of `project_b`'s master branch, just do

```
git cherry-pick project_b/master
```

Alternatively, you can bypass the remote fetching/cherry-picking stuff and just patch directly from `project_b` like so:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/project_b/.git format-patch -k -1 \
--stdout <commit SHA> somefile.cpp | git am -3 -k
```

([Adapted from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9507417/349353).)

Answer (score 3):

In case you have files with the same name but in different folders (lets assume that you had project_b merged into a subdir) then you have to do the cherry pick in the following fashion

```
git cherry-pick project_b/master --strategy=subtree
```