# What to do if git-am fails with “does not exist in index”?

Tags: git, git-am

I have a patch that gives out the following output when I try to apply it with git am

```
Checking patch old/filename...
error: old/filename: does not exist in index
```

Within the patch old/filename is actually moved to new/filename but it seems the original file is already missing from the source tree.

So what is the error about and how to solve / work-around it? Can it just be ignored (with --reject or so)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The patch was not created against the correct source tree.

One way this could happen:

Assume your original branch (the one you want to apply the patch to) has commits:

1. 1a -> 1b -> 1c -> 1d

This branch is then cloned, and new commits are made:

2. 1a -> 1b -> 1c -> 1d -> 1e

Commit 1e included old/filename

Now you do the work in the patch, based on the second branch, not the original one:

3. 1a -> 1b -> 1c -> 1d -> 1e -> 1f

Commit 1f included the rename old/filename -> new/filename

Now, if you create a patch for commit 1f, you won't be able to apply it on top of commit 1d, because commit 1e is missing where old/filename was added to the index/repository.

Comment: You can quick double check if the file that git is complaining about still exists. I ran into this issue just now, and the file git was complaining about had been actually moved by a co-worker of mine, and hence the issue. Git cherry-pick is smarter regarding such issues, and that worked great for me (you will have to do this commit by commit though).

Comment: so as per question. what should he do then?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--reject` to get it to do its 
best and output the rest in `.rej` files. Then you can fix it up 
manually and commit.

Tip extracted from: [Raymes Khoury](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/XcxhD9GGvp4).

Comment: --reject won't work with files not found. Only if the patch cannot be applied but file is found

Answer (score 2):

'git am" does not give very clear location of failure.  I did the following:
Use "patch -p n patch_file" to try.  This unix "patch" command shows clearly where the rejection happens.  If patch command works, then the patch file is fine.

I saw "patch -p n" command worked, but "git am -p n" stilled failed with vague and confusing error message "does not exist in index".  I suspected it just could not find the right file.  So I tweaked n to n-1.  Then it worked.

So, the actual cause is that -p arg should be fed with n-1, where n is the right one for the "patch" command.

In short, the working command is "git am -p n-1 patch_file".

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, applying the patch from one repo to another with different commits in between as described by Jacques: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27998109/9478470

Remark, the files to which I tried to apply the patch were not moved (same relative path).
What helped was "using a three-way merge" as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16968982/9478470

`git am -3 < changes.patch`

Found it through Matt's comment on a similar problem: [How can I generate a Git patch for a specific commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658313/how-can-i-generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit#comment51607318_6658352)