# Git move commit to different local repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn, patch

I have two local git repositories, both cloned from different svn repositories:

1. `git-6.1-pa (latest svn branch)`
2. `git-6.0-pa (stable svn branch, different source code tree, but similar to 6.1)`

Currently, I have in `git-6.1-pa` reviewed and committed to svn repository revision (by git svn dcommit) - `e27cf8edb2f69daf054aa6bb379d668e4b3d52f0` with own git-svn-id.

What I want - to move this commit to another local `git-6.0-pa` repository.

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9507417/966467) and it works great, but... I got:

```
1. Successfully applied commit.
2. This commit is not on top of history (3rd)
3. Contains unnecessary old git-svn-id, because I'm going to call git svn dcommit on this moved commit.
```

and I want to get:

```
1. Successfully applied commit (or diff suitable to commit).
2. Commit is on top of history (or diff suitable to commit)
3. Doesn't contain old git-svn-id, that I can just call git svn dcommit
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your item 3), old git-svn id is not a problem. It will be ignored and overridden when you do `git svn dcommit`. If you are concerned about it - do `git commit --amend` or  `git rebase -i` with `r` option to amend the comment.

Your issue 2) is not very clear to me. If you don't like the order in which your commit it cherry-picked, you can change it with the help of git rebase interactive ( `git rebase -i <some sha earlier>` ), but you should not do that with the commits that are coming from your linked svn. I am still surprised how did you get your commit "not on the top of the history". Normally if you do a cherry-pick, the new commit will be added on top of your HEAD. Did you working copy point to the "top of the history" before you did the cherry-pick?