# git: how to get 2 commits from one git workarea into another empty git repository

Tags: git

I have a workingarea git repository with many commits.  I want to pick 2 of the commits and put them into a new empty bare repository.  So then the new repository will only have the 2 commits in it.  Is this possible?

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120038/is-it-possible-to-cherry-pick-a-commit-from-another-git-repository

Comment: Go for git cherrypick.

Comment: If it's really only 2 commits you want, I would use `git archive` to create `tar` files of the two commits and import them manually (`git rm -r *; tar xf path/to/commit1.tar; git add -A .; git commit -m "first commit"`, and then similarly for the second...).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to cherry-pick a commit from another git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120038/is-it-possible-to-cherry-pick-a-commit-from-another-git-repository)