# Is it possible to create patch using format-patch from another server?

Tags: git

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120038/is-it-possible-to-cherry-pick-a-commit-from-another-git-repository/9507417#9507417) SO answer:

```
$ git --git-dir=../<some_other_repo>/.git \
format-patch -k -1 --stdout <commit SHA> | \
git am -3 -k
```

Is it possible to do same across servers? in other words, if git-dir is in different physical server, is it possible to use something like: `--git-dir=otherServerName:/path/to/repo/.git` ?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to add the server as a remote:

```
$ git remote add <remote-name> <remote-uri>
```

Then fetch the changes:

```
$ git fetch <remote-name>
```

Now you have the commit directly on your machine without modifying any of your local branches. You can create a patch as in your question without the `--get-dir` option. If you want the commit with your current work, you can use `git cherry-pick` or any other appropriate git commands using the SHA hash directly.

Answer (score 0):

The git way would be to add the server temporarily as a **remote** repo and to **cherry-pick** the commit.

```
git remote add <name> <url>
git fetch <name>
git cherry-pick <commit SHA>
git remote remove <name>
```

---

If the repo, for example, is on GitHub or GitLab you could do something like this:

```
curl https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/commit/<commit SHA>.patch | \
git am -3 -k
```

*Check the API documentation of your git server.*