# Git Merge a Folder into a Repository using a Specified Ancestor Folder

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a git repository, call it `Repo1`:

```
Repo1
    Folder1
    Other stuff...
```

and I have two folders that contain a subset of the files in `Repo1`. A `Baseline` folder:

```
Baseline
    Folder1
```

...and a `ChangeSet` folder:

```
ChangeSet
    Folder1
```

`Baseline` contains the files from `Repo1` that represent the common ancestor of any files in `ChangeSet`.

I'd like to do a 3-way merge of the changes from `ChangeSet` into `Repo1`.  I've looked into creating a temporary repository containing two commits, the first for the baseline, and the second for the changeset, and then merging with `--allow-unrelated-histories`:

```
git merge <remote> --no-commit --allow-unrelated-histories
```

...but this appears to mark any changes as conflicts, and doesn't seem to use the ancestor at all.

I'm guessing that I could use `git-merge-file` to merge any non-binary files that may exist in all three locations, and then handling all binary conflicts, added, deleted files etc. myself, but I wonder if there is a more straightforward solution.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: From the answer below, `Changeset` was probably the wrong choice of words for the updated files folder.  Probably a better word would be `Snapshot`

**Update 2021**: The completed script for this question is now on GitHub as [git-stash2d](https://github.com/danericweiner/git-stash2d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** You're on the right track in your own answer: cherry-pick is almost certainly the way to go, for your actual case.  The trick is to put their original tree in as an "orphan branch" (independent commit) and then to put their patch in as the second commit on this branch, then to go back to your own branch and use `git cherry-pick`.  Cherry-picking is internally implemented as a full three-way merge, with the merge base being the parent of the commit being cherry-picked and the `--theirs` commit being the commit you name.

#### Instructions

In your original repository (or an added work-tree for that repository, if you don't want to mess with your main work-tree), do:

```sh
git checkout --orphan xxx         # use any name you like here
git read-tree -m -u 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
```

The hash ID here is that of [the empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452).  Using `--empty` logically should work here but doesn't.  Or instead of the read-tree, use:

```
git rm -r .
```

which does exactly the same thing, and as a bonus is easier to type in, but looks scarier, somehow.

Your work-tree should now be empty and `git status` will say:

```
On branch xxx

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

If your work-tree is not empty, it contained untracked files before, and still does.  You should move or remove them (or, again, you can do this all in an added work-tree).

Now do what you suggested in your own answer:

```
# copy my Baseline folder changes in
git add .
git commit -m "baseline"
```

(side note: do not use `git commit -a`; it doesn't do what you want).

I had understood "changeset" to mean "a diff you will apply", rather than "a new set of files".  Changeset is the wrong word to describe a new snapshot, but if that's a new snapshot, it's now time to empty out the work-tree again:

```
git rm -r .
```

to use the version that is easier to type in.  Then, again almost straight from your own answer:

```sh
# copy my ChangeSet folder changes in
git add .
git commit -m "code"
```

You can now `git checkout master` and `git cherry-pick xxx`.  Substitute in whatever branch name you're using to hold the two commits.

[Original answer below.]

---

> I'd like to do a 3-way merge of the changes from `ChangeSet` into `Repo1`. I've looked into creating a temporary repository containing two commits,

You're at least one short.  A merge has *three* inputs, not two:

> the first for the baseline, and the second for the changeset, and then merging with --allow-unrelated-histories:

You're on the right track with using the first one for the baseline.

The other two that you need are:

- one with baseline-plus-changes: this is *their* code, or the `--theirs` side of the merge, and
- one with your code: this is the `--ours` side of the merge.  This is the commit you will have out as `HEAD` as a result of running `git checkout`.

Both of these two commits must descend, historically speaking, from the baseline.  That way Git can compare the *merge base* snapshot—in this case, the baseline—to each of the two *branch tip* snapshots: your code, and their-code-as-modified-by-their-changeset.

Hence:

```
# create initial commit in initial repository:
git init         # create new empty repository
...              # copy baseline into place
git add .
git commit

# add their changeset as a new commit on a branch:
git checkout -b theirs
... apply the changeset, perhaps with "git apply" ...
git add -u       # or git add . again, or similar
git commit

# add your version of the code as a new commit on master:
git checkout master
... copy your code into place ...
git add .        # or similar
git commit
```

Now you can run `git merge theirs`.  The three inputs are a merge base commit, your current commit—the tip of `master`, also known as `HEAD`—and the commit you name: the tip commit of branch `theirs`.

The `git merge` command locates the merge base commit on its own. In this case, it's the baseline files, in the initial commit.  The `git merge` command now produces two changesets:

- baseline vs `HEAD`: this is what *you* changed;
- baseline vs `theirs`: this is what *they* changed.

Note that this second comparison produces the changeset you used to create the `theirs` commit and its snapshot.  This might seem like wasted effort—why not just give Git the changeset directly?—but it's just how Git itself is built: Git really needs that snapshot, so you have to make it.

#### What if you already have a repository, and would like to do the work directly there?

In this case, you're in a bit of a bind (in the sense of "problematic situation").  Git finds the merge base on its own.  You cannot just tell Git: *do a merge, pretending that commit C is the merge base* for some arbitrary commit C.<sup>1</sup>

One option is to rewrite your entire repository into a structure that allows this.  This is generally a bad idea unless you really want to switch over to a new history, discarding all clones as well.

Another is to create a second repostiory, or an independent sub-graph within your repository.  This works fine: use `git checkout --orphan` and `git read-tree --empty -u` to get a clean slate for the new disconnected branches (don't call the main one `master`, of course).  You can then tie the new merge commit into the original history in your main graph.  This is slightly tricky.

A third is to use `git replace` to insert a parent graph, so that your repository seems to have a new root commit.  This is also slightly tricky.  It's equivalent to the second method except that it leaves fewer traces of how you did it: whether you leave the replacement commit in place or not, it does not get copied on clone operations, so others trying to figure out how you did what you did, will probably be puzzled.

The last option is the one you described yourself:

> ... I could use `git-merge-file` to merge any non-binary files that may exist in all three locations, and then handling all binary conflicts, added, deleted files etc. myself ...

This method also works fine, and you can automate a lot of it with a script; it's just still a bit more painful than having Git do it.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, you *can* do this, using `git merge-recursive`.  This command is not meant to be run by a user, though.  There is no documentation telling you *how* to run it, and the arguments are complicated: some of them are supplied as environment variables!  Don't do it this way.

Comment: The cherry-pick trick won't work as is, but *will* work if you put the two new commits into your own repository as independent commits. This actually might be the best approach! I'll add a recipe at the top of my own answer.

Comment: Can you explain a couple things?  1. Why won't the answer I posted work as is?  It seems like the same thing since the `git apply` falls back to a `--3way` merge.  Also, I'd rather not have to remove all the files in my tree as that would cause other issues.  So 2. What's an "added work-tree"?  Also, I'm not surprised I got `commit -a -m` wrong, since I usually use a bunch of aliases for that kind of thing, so thanks again.  I'll fix my answer.

Comment: The issue with doing the cherry-pick while pointing `--git-dir` at a Git with just the two commits in it is, you don't have a third commit. (Given that Git might treat the current index as the third commit, it *might* work, if you add `-n` to the options.) For the added work-tree, see `git worktree`: this requires Git 2.5 or later, preferably 2.15 since there was a terrible bug until then (won't hit until your added work-tree is over 2 weeks old though, which is why it went unnoticed for so long).

Comment: Last: The `-a` option to `git commit` is roughly equivalent to using `git add -u` before running `git commit`: it doesn't pick up totally-new-to-Git files.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't written the entire script yet, but here's what I think will work.

First, do what I said here:

> I've looked into creating a temporary repository containing two commits, the first for the baseline, and the second for the changeset.

So I'll create a temporary repository containing my commit to baseline like:

```
mkdir Temp
cd Temp
git init
# copy my Baseline folder changes in
git add --all
git commit -m "baseline"
rm -rf <folder>
# copy my ChangeSet folder changes in
git add --all
git commit -m "code"
```

Then I just need to cherry-pick it to my `Repo1` repository, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120038/is-it-possible-to-cherry-pick-a-commit-from-another-git-repository):

Original answer using a patch - which may not be ideal:

```
git --git-dir='path\to\Temp\.git' format-patch -1 --stdout HEAD | git apply --3way
```

Updated answer using a straight cherry-pick:

```
git fetch 'path\to\Temp'
git cherry-pick -n FETCH_HEAD
```