# In git, how do I sync my tags against a remote server?

Tags: git, git-tag

Is there a way to keep my local git tags in lockstep with a remote's tags? That is -- not only get new tags when created (as usual, when `fetch`-ing/`pull`-ing), but also prune tags no longer on a remote and also delete existing tags when someone else `git push -f`'s a tag.
I know I can `git fetch remotename` followed by `git remote prune remotename` to achieve similar behaviour for branches.

Comment: Looks a bit like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841341/remove-local-tags-that-are-no-longer-on-the-remote-repository

Comment: Note: with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), a simple `git config fetch.pruneTags true` will make your `git fetch` do what you want! See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215190/6309).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

> ...also prune tags no longer on a remote

`git fetch` gets with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018) an handy short-hand for getting
rid of stale tags that are locally held.

See [commit 6317972](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6317972cff9b4df7a6cc666b08be7133ba81617c), [commit 97716d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97716d217c1ea00adfc64e4f6bb85c1236d661ff), [commit e249ce0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e249ce0ccdb5c57f45a88daa25d24c5b602ee6e9), [commit 627a129](https://github.com/git/git/commit/627a129b46530773369586f7982925fd41dc7227), [commit d0e0747](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0e07472faa938c83e9b1f76567f16614672668c), [commit 2c72ed7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c72ed740f302bf51e6cd0824b8e7cbde1b1e8c2), [commit e1790f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1790f9245f120940be9333b09015e04a8e73127), [commit 59caf52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59caf52d094494a8c02dd7f15302891678533182), [commit 82f34e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82f34e03e91af42a020f15a1d248bc75785c565a), [commit 6fb23f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fb23f56c16c0981a2f7b46f53ac3af12b247996), [commit ca3065e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ca3065e7e7bcb406043f8202ef672f884eeb925d), [commit bf16ab7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf16ab795574c27ffa0fe180cede2d355de41619), [commit eca142d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eca142d30818bd9cfc0d3a6b38d6ae4dc4c500a0), [commit 750d0da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/750d0da9cfbc2519f1ef478d50de0ce549c41f05), [commit 0711883](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0711883218039750f940d8febf05a81aa46d2ab9), [commit ce3ab21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce3ab21b0c179559621fb7450a6f8c24e0a28ddb), [commit aa59e0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa59e0eaf65b1e535248f67822053e3b2f5fcc26) (09 Feb 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c1a7902](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1a7902f9adda4c3a64de99d565cf9982f12b1d9), 06 Mar 2018)</sup>

> ### **fetch**: add a `--prune-tags` option and `fetch.pruneTags` config

> Add a `--prune-tags` option to `git-fetch`, along with `fetch.pruneTags` config option and a `-P` shorthand (`-p` is `--prune`).
> This allows for doing any of:
>
> ```
> git fetch -p -P
> git fetch --prune --prune-tags
> git fetch -p -P origin
> git fetch --prune --prune-tags origin
> ```
>
> Or simply:
>
> ```
> git config fetch.prune true &&
> git config fetch.pruneTags true &&
> git fetch
> ```
>
> Instead of the much more verbose:
>
> ```
> git fetch --prune origin 'refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*' '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
> ```
>
> **Before this feature** it was painful to support the use-case of pulling
> from a repo which is having both its branches *and* tags deleted
> regularly, and have our local references to reflect upstream.
>
> At work we create deployment tags in the repo for each rollout, and
> there's *lots* of those, so they're archived within weeks for
> performance reasons.
>
> **Without this change** it's hard to centrally configure such repos in
> `/etc/gitconfig` (on servers that are only used for working with
> them). You need to set `fetch.prune=true` globally, and then for each
> repo:
>
> ```
> git -C {} config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch "refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*" "^\+*refs/tags/\*:refs/tags/\*$"
> ```
>
> Now I can simply set **`fetch.pruneTags=true`** in `/etc/gitconfig` as well,
> and users running "`git pull`" will automatically get the pruning
> semantics I want.

---

Update Apr. 2021, Git for Windows 2.30.1 and [GitHub Desktop 2.8](https://github.blog/2021-04-28-github-desktop-hiding-whitespace-expanding-diffs-repo-aliases/)

It works if you have set `prune` *and* `pruneTags` options:

```
cd C:\path\to\local\repo
git config fetch.prune true
git config fetch.pruneTags true
```

Then click on Fetch origin in GitHub Deskop: the logs will show:

```
2021-04-28T20:25:21.244Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: 
  git -c credential.helper= -c protocol.version=2 fetch --progress --prune origin (took 2.986s)
```

... and any local tag not present in the remote will be gone!

Comment: Color me impressed! This a hell of a follow up over the years since I originally asked.

Comment: @mlb Thank you. That feature is not yet released, but should be part of Git 2.17 scheduled for release at the very beginning of April 2018.

Comment: @realtebo What Git version are you using?

Comment: git version 2.13.2.windows.1 on windows 10, both using powershell and git bash for windows

Comment: @realtebo Well... the non-verbose form has only been implemented in 2.17, released last week ;) https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.17.0.windows.1

Comment: I'll wait, because git for windows is still at 2.16. thanks for fast reply.

Comment: @realtebo No Git for Windows is at 2.17, not 2.16. Just unzip the https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.17.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want, set a simplified PATH for testing (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688159/6309) and you are good to go.

Comment: None of this worked (2.28, windows). Produced no errors, but failed to remove tags that didn't exist on remote. [Only this worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10644209/616460).

Comment: @JasonC OK, strange. It does work just fine on my repos.

Comment: @VonC This particular repo is primarily managed with GitHub Desktop, and tags are primarily managed with the GitHub web interface (via the releases/tags UI); could be a quirk related to that. Not sure.

Comment: @JasonC Indeed. I will update my GitHub Desktop to the latest version (2.8: https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-28-github-desktop-2-8-includes-expanding-diffs-hiding-whitespace-and-repository-aliases/) and test it out.

Comment: @JasonC I have updated GitHub Desktop, made some test, and reported my findings in the (now edited) answer. In short: it just works <sup>(TM)</sup>.

Answer (score 49):

The following worked for me:

```
git fetch --prune --tags
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. A bit more straightforward than the accepted answer, in my opinion.

Comment: The same works for branches aswell if you leave out the --tags

Comment: Don't know why I hadn't thought of this originally. Much simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer : the git documentation (for V1.9.4) explicitly says that this will NOT work.

Comment: No, you cannot delete any local tags by just doing ´git fetch -p -t´

Comment: I have git version 2.12.0 on my Mac and yet --prune still does work

Comment: @DominikEhrenberg I find that it doesn't delete tags locally that have already been deleted in the remote.  It only fetches new tags at best.  Maybe this is the reason (from man git fetch): `Tags are not subject to pruning if they are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a --tags option`.  I'm on git 2.7.4

Comment: Works like a charm)

Comment: Didn't work (2.28, windows). Produced no errors, but failed to remove tags that didn't exist on remote. [Only this worked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10644209/616460).

Answer (score 21):

A bit of research has shown that *git* has no way to tell the difference between local or foreign tags (all tags go to .git/refs/tags/). Therefore, it is not possible to determine the difference between locally created tags and prune-able remote tags. The options, are then reduced to: having an ever growing set of tags, or only the tags that are on the server.

```
git push --tags origin && \
git tag | xargs -n1 git tag -d && \
git fetch --tags
```

Drop the first line for the latter behaviour, and could be potentially git alias'd for frequent usage.

An alternative would be to create a branch (as they can be identified as local/remote) at a tag point and are never write to it again. Then using remotename/branchname as a tag to checkout would keep tags in sync (in addition to `git fetch` and `git remote prune remotename`).

Either way is a hack, and the "right" answer is to stop changing tags all the time.

Comment: It's also possible to supply all tags inline to `git tag -d`, thus `git tag | xargs git tag -d && git fetch --tags` worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

Another solution which actually works for me:

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d && git fetch -t
```

Comment: This works, but can take long on a long history of tags

Answer (score 14):

use these command to sync tags(delete all local then fetch all remote)

```
git tag -d $(git tag) # delete all local tags
git fetch --all # fetch all remote to local
```

Comment: This is exactly the information I needed. Worked like a champ.

Comment: This one worked when the other did not. I had been getting this error `! [rejected]          7.34       -> 7.34  (would clobber existing tag)` And none of the other methods worked. Thank you!!!

Comment: simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 8):

git push --tags will push your local tags up to the server. By default, git fetch (the first half of git pull or git pull --rebase)  will pull tags, but you can specify -t or --tags to pull all of them.

I'm not sure how to prune remotely deleted tags, but the fetch should pull down any force-updated tags.

Answer (score 5):

**disclaimer** this uses git internals (some may argue that the filesystem *is* a git interface, but that's for another day :D)

```
# Blow away all local tags, this will remove any that are tagged locally
# but are not on the remote
rm .git/refs/tags/*

# Download all the tags from the remote
git fetch --tags
```

Comment: This won't always work -- sometimes tags are stored in .git/info/refs and not in .git/refs/tags/*

I am still researching the interplay between those two locations, but simply clearing .git/refs/tags/* is certainly not a foolproof way to clear tags.

Comment: @PhilWhittington I haven't found a situation where it doesn't work -- and it doesn't sound like you have either?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution:

```
git fetch -p +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

From the [git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) doc:

> -p
>   --prune
>
> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer
>   exist on the remote. Tags are not subject to pruning if they are
>   fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a
>   --tags option. However, **if tags are fetched due to an explicit refspec** (either on the command line or in the remote configuration, for
>   example if the remote was cloned with the --mirror option), **then they
>   are also subject to pruning**.