# Git: warning: refname 'master' is ambiguous

Tags: git

I saw a few people asking the same question on here but it seems none of their advice is applicable to me. I'm getting the warning that is in the title of this but I don't have any tags named "master". This is the result of `git branch -a`:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

Any idea what could be going wrong here? I've only been using git for a few months now, so it mostly just worries me that this ambiguity might mess with the repo in the future.

Comment: what command issues the warning?

Comment: Would the list of possible 'master' mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12225704/6309 help? A `git checkout heads/master`should work (without warning)

Comment: Please show the output of `git show-ref`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Sorry for the delay here, but the output of `git show-ref` is a bunch of stuff that wouldn't fit here. I believe it might be relevant that there are two lines that end in "master": refs/remotes/origin/master, refs/heads/master

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: refname 'master' is ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224773/git-refname-master-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

For me I tracked down the source of this warning to much earlier when I incorrectly issued an "update-ref" command.  If you forget to specify the full refs/heads/mybranchname path in the first arg, then a file .git/mybranchname gets created, which later leads to this warning when you try to switch to that branch.

It is solved by simply deleting the .git/mybranchname, eg:

```
rm .git/master
```

And for reference, the correct form for the update-ref command is:

```
git update-ref refs/heads/mybranchname mytargetbranch
```

Don't forget the "refs/heads" part!

Also, my most common use-case for update-ref is simply manually moving a branch to point to another commit, which I've found a simpler syntax to do:

`git branch -f myBranchToMove destinationBranchOrHash`

This syntax is easier for me because it doesn't require that error-prone refs/heads path qualifier.

Comment: I did the exact same thing. The command didn't seem to do anything, though, so I added the "refs/heads" part and didn't realize it had left residue in the .git directory.

Comment: `git update-ref -d master` also works, once you realize it's the update-ref command that created the duplicate ref.

Comment: If you only want to move a branch between commits it is preferred to delete the branch (branch -d) and re-create it on the other commit (checkout -b). That does not require any fiddling with refs.

Answer (score 33):

As detailed in "[Git: refname '`master`' is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224773/git-refname-master-is-ambiguous/12225704#12225704)", that means that, beside `heads/master`, you have another master in one of the following namespace within the git repo:

```
refs/<refname> 
refs/tags/<refname>
refs/heads/<refname>
refs/remotes/<refname>
refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD
```

Or even `./<refname>`, as mentioned in [Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426877/magnus)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16302266/6309).

Comment: or just `./<refname>` as Magnus mentioned. (this was in my case)

Answer (score 31):

For future reference, I had the same issue and what ended up to work for me was the solution described [here](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/ba8905). Basically, when you get `Git: warning: refname 'xxx' is ambiguous` warning, you can use: `git show-ref xxx` to check the references to `xxx` branch and validate which ones are having conflict.

In my scenario, it was a tag named `xxx` and branch name with the same name. The tag had been made by mistake and was removed from server so all I needed to do was to update my local tag to match the server: `git fetch -p -P`. This command is explained in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215190/1450348)

Comment: I had the same issue with tag - production. Thanks)

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem (not master) when I created a branch with the same name as a tag.

This helped me remove the tag https://stackoverflow.com/a/5480292/150953

```
git push --delete origin tagname
```

Comment: Scott - Is there any way to stop users from creating tag name similar to branch

Comment: @Paul I  am sorry I don't know. You would think git would just not let you do it but it does.

Comment: Can you pls help to create a webhook to check for tags with name develop and delete it after every push?

Answer (score 9):

```
git fetch --prune

git pull origin branch-name
```

should fix your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Check your `.git/config` file. You may run into this problem if you have more than one remote repo configured with the same:

`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

The other remote server should have a different name, eg.:

`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/another_repo/*`

Comment: Whoa... real necromancer here. I asked this 8 years ago... back in the days when I was still figuring out what the hell git was. I had probably twisted my commit tree into a knot. Who knows what it was. Thanks for still offering new avenues of investigation to those in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I got that error after creating a new branch locally with the same name as an existing one on remote.

The error was something like this

```
warning: refname <<branch-name> is ambiguous
```

I had to (force) delete the local branch and then create a new one with a different name to the remote existing one, like this:

```
$ git branch -D <local-branch>
```