# How to move master to branch without merge

Tags: git, merge, branch

Is there a reset command that will move the master to another branch without merging? I have some unstable experimental code on branch MIN-791 which has already been merged to the master. I'd rather not deal with it if I don't have to for now. I'd like the MIN-780-493 branch to become the master branch since it has a couple of nice repairs but none of the crap. 'git reset sha#' didn't seem to do the trick. Is there another reset command that will? Or something else? I don't want to lose the changes on MIN-791 since it is still being used to fix a difficult bug, but don't want it in my releases.[image: SourceTree]

Comment: Please clarify *`git reset sha#` didn't seem to do the trick*. Did you get an error? What SHA did you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are checked out to master then this

```
git reset --hard SHA
```

That will also modify the staging area and working directory.

If you just want to randomly assign values to refs then you would use

```
git update-ref refs/heads/master SHA
```

Comment: WRONG update-ref OPTIONS!  Make sure to use git update-ref refs/heads/master SHA.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073062/git-warning-refname-master-is-ambiguous -- Leaving off the refs/heads/ will eventually cause you to have ambiguous masters and a scary looking log

Answer (score 2):

Andrew C's answer is right. In addition you can just use the branch name instead of the SHA.

Ex:

```
git reset --hard origin/MIN-780-493
```