# How to overwrite remote specific branches on git fetch?

Tags: git, git-fetch

I have setup a central backup server which has all the developer repos added as remotes. I fetch everyday from all the remotes. It gives me all the branches of developers as `dev1/master`, `dev1/FeatureA`, `dev2/master`, `dev2/Hotfix` etc. I do this so that I have backup of user repos in case a local system crashes. Things are all fine.

The problem that I face is:
When say `dev1`'s Repo has 2 branches `Br1` and `Br2` that are tracked on backup via `dev1/Br1` and `dev1.Br2` respectively. Now the developer deletes one of the branches, say `Br1`. I do a fetch at EOD on backup server. The backup server still shows that `dev1` has `Br1` branch.

**How can I make fetch replace all existing branches with the new ones, i.e. also delete `dev1/Br1` if the remote (`dev1`) repo deletes the branch?**

Comment: I assume you're using `fetch =` lines to do the repo branch name mappings.  Just add `--prune` to your `git remote update` or `git fetch`.  Note that some older git versions occasionally fail to prune with some commands, so if one doesn't work, try the other, or update your git version.

Comment: also an interesting attempt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository

Comment: @user3415653 bundles are out of option. I am having a backup of 100+ users and bundling each and unbundling is just too costly.

Comment: @MudassirRazvi then use a enterprise solution like stash (https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash)

Comment: @user3415653: That is also out of option. Palec's answer below works awesome. Could you suggest a way I can prune tags also along with branches. That would be helpful... :)

Comment: @MudassirRazvi i think `git fetch <remote> --prune --tags`

Comment: git fetch <remote> --prune --tags for some reason deletes all remote tracking branches. never use it..:p

Comment: @MudassirRazvi You should really consider using stash or a similar product.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like:

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

From the manual:

```
--all
    Fetch all remotes.

-p, --prune
    After fetching, remove any remote tracking branches which no longer
    exist on the remote.
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. But is there a way that Tags can also be pruned? Coz this way it removes branches perfectly but tags that are deleted in remote still stay

Comment: @MudassirRazvi `git fetch --all --prune --tags` that simple.

Comment: @Zarathustra Agreed. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10491146/2157640 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1841341/2157640

Comment: @MudassirRazvi If adding `--tags` does not work, you can call `git tag -l | xargs git tag -d` before the fetch as a work-around. This deletes all tags in the repository and they will be fetched from scratch.