# git - Tags with the same name with a branch

Tags: git, tags, branch

I was kind of freaking out why on earth `git diff branch1 branch2` is showing irrelevant things (it was like it's comparing branch1 with an OLDER version of branch2)

Until I found out we have some tags with the same name with a branch!

Other than diff, that makes problems on pull/push (ambiguous ref name error...), and possibly checkout...

So I want to find all these tags so that I can delete them

Comment: The simple command for this is `git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' | sort | uniq -d`, to show all punned short names.  If you want to delete all the punned tags, `git tag -d $(that pipeline)`.

Comment: In git commands (diff, push, etc) you can disambiguate, e.g. `git diff refs/heads/branchname refs/tags/branchname` (but it is nonetheless wise to avoid this ambiguity)

Comment: You should never name a tag and a branch the same name! Refer: https://geedew.com/fixing-git-branch-and-tag-name-collision

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, we extract all the tags:

```
git tag | sort > tags
```

And branches, if you want to check this with local branches:

```
git branch | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sort > branches
```

Or branches of a specific remote, like `origin`

```
git branch -r | grep origin/  | sed -e 's:^[ \t]*origin/::' | sort > branches
```

After extracting tags and branches (in sorted order), we find the common lines in these 2 files:

```
comm -1 -2 tags branches > bad-tags
```

And view the file `bad-tags`
Then we can delete all of them:

```
cat bad-tags | xargs git tag -d
```

Answer (score 4):

[saeedgnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495838/saeedgnu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32609196/6309) is on the right track, but uses many additional shell commands.

Instead of using `| sort`, both [`git tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#git-tag---sortltkeygt) and [`git branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch---sortltkeygt) have a `--sort=<key>` option, with `<key>` based on [`git for-each-ref` field names](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names) and [using a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41403591/6309).

By default, the default sort order, both for branches and tags, is already by **refname**.

And since Git 2.19 (Q3 2018), `git branch` supports a config `branch.sort`, like `git tag` already had a config `tag.sort`.
See [commit 560ae1c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/560ae1c164ad040a389ccc47834dce8c15447294) (16 Aug 2018) by [Samuel Maftoul (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d89db6f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d89db6f4c3fceea7bc9e66823c7a04920e95ac1d), 27 Aug 2018)</sup>

So:

- no need to sort `git tag`: they are already sorted by default by refname, unless a `tag.sort` config had been set.
  But to be on the safe side, use at least `git tag --sort="refname"` (no `| sort` needed)
- no need to `grep origin`, `sed` or `sort` (unless a `branch.sort` config had been set): use a pattern and a format:

  ```
  git branch -r --list 'origin/*' --format="%(refname:lstrip=3)"
  ```

The format transforms a `remotes/origin/aBranchName` into `aBranchName`.
The pattern '`origin/*`' makes sure we are selecting the remote branches of the right remote repo.

That gives you pure git commands:

```
git tag --sort="refname" > tags
git branch -r --list 'origin/*' --format="%(refname:lstrip=3)"
comm -1 -2 tags branches > bad-tags
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition of scripting (with pure git commands) the number of bad tags, Git 2.20 (Q4 2018) offers an alternative to *avoid* having to get tags with the same name with a branch.

The rules used by "`git push`" and "`git fetch`" to determine if a ref can or cannot be updated were inconsistent; specifically, fetching to update existing tags were allowed even though tags are supposed to be unmoving anchoring points.
"`git fetch`" was taught to forbid updates to existing tags without the "`--force`" option.

See [commit 0bc8d71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0bc8d71b99e91c9e90b519073b639a5066119591), [commit ae6a470](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae6a470334d7d0e086e289f0c7e492e3366b66aa), [commit fe802bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fe802bd21e81cceedff2db79cc3c9a5ad75b4f93), [commit 8da6128](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8da6128c264c7896c011b5e3e0eace57eb073f63), [commit d931455](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d931455acf1cf1a21a4f10fd99fc2bd9bbefa7a9), [commit 6b0b067](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b0b0677f6d92932bacd73981a47724b543dfd90), [commit 253b3d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/253b3d4f57266449c4351e992263eb1cf615a0ae), [commit f08fb8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f08fb8dfea403497e2070cb9778ceafcf799a615), [commit 8cd4b7c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8cd4b7c14895a055de01962237d580173e5beca1) (31 Aug 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d39cab3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d39cab3989f9e660cae124f78143369b13ad2901), 17 Sep 2018)</sup>

> ### `fetch`: stop clobbering existing tags without `--force`
>
> Change "`fetch`" to treat "`+`" in refspecs (aka `--force`) to mean we
>   should clobber a local tag of the same name.
>
> This changes the long-standing behavior of "`fetch`" added in [853a369](https://github.com/git/git/commit/853a3697dc2bc609650c38ed03a1f8fa9f145f97) ("[PATCH] Multi-head fetch.", 2005-08-20, Git 0.99.5).
>   Before this change, all tag fetches effectively had `--force` enabled.
>   See the [`git-fetch-script` code in `fast_forward_local()` with the comment](https://github.com/git/git/blob/853a3697dc2bc609650c38ed03a1f8fa9f145f97/git-fetch-script#L55-L61):
>
> > Tags need not be pointing at commits so there is no way to
> >     guarantee "fast-forward" anyway.
>
> That commit and the rest of the history of "`fetch`" shows that the "`+`" (`--force`) part of refpecs was only conceived for branch updates, while tags have accepted any changes from upstream unconditionally and clobbered the local tag object. Changing this behavior [has been discussed as early as 2011](https://public-inbox.org/git/20111123221658.GA22313@sigill.intra.peff.net/).
>
> The current behavior doesn't make sense to me, it easily results in local tags accidentally being clobbered.
>   We could namespace our tags per-remote and not locally populate `refs/tags/*`, but as with my [97716d2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97716d217c1ea00adfc64e4f6bb85c1236d661ff) ("`fetch`: add a `--prune-tags` option and `fetch.pruneTags` config", 2018-02-09, Git 2.17) it's easier to work around the current implementation than to fix the root cause.

(See "[In Git, how do I sync my tags against a remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215190/6309)")

> So this change implements [suggestion #1 from Jeff's 2011 E-Mail](https://public-inbox.org/git/20111123221658.GA22313@sigill.intra.peff.net/), "`fetch`" now only clobbers the tag if either "`+`" is provided as part of the refspec, or if "`--force`" is provided on the command-line.
>
> This also makes it nicely symmetrical with how "`tag`" itself works when
>   creating tags.
>   I.e. we refuse to clobber any existing tags unless "`--force`" is supplied.
>   Now we can refuse all such clobbering, whether it would happen by clobbering a local tag with "`tag`", or by fetching it from the remote with "`fetch`".
>
> Ref updates outside `refs/{tags,heads/*` are still still not symmetrical with how "`git push`" works, [as discussed in the recently changed `pull-fetch-param.txt` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/150f307afc13961b0322ad0e7205a7b193368586/Documentation/pull-fetch-param.txt#L46-L58).
>   This change brings the two divergent behaviors more into line with one another. I don't think there's any reason "fetch" couldn't fully converge with the behavior used by "`push`", but that's a topic for another change.