# What is the format of <pattern> in git-branch --list

Tags: git

As title, I have read [the manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) but in vain.

What I found is that a `*` can be wildcard pattern matching.

```
git branch --list 'issues*6'
 issues/586
 issues/616
```

However, it's found by myself instead of mentioned in manual page.

I wonder what is the real format of `<pattern>`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Quoting from that same [manual page you linked](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html):

> If `--list` is given, or if there are no non-option arguments, existing branches are listed; the current branch will be highlighted with an asterisk. Option `-r` causes the remote-tracking branches to be listed, and option `-a` shows both local and remote branches. **If a `<pattern>` is given, it is used as a shell wildcard to restrict the output to matching branches.** If multiple patterns are given, a branch is shown if it matches any of the patterns. Note that when providing a `<pattern>`, you must use `--list`; otherwise the command is interpreted as branch creation.

So the answer, at least according to the documentation, is that "it is used as a shell wildcard".  This assumes, of course, that you know what the phrase "shell wildcard" means—and more importantly, it's *wrong*, since a straight shell wildcard would not match across the `/`.

The documentation should say something like: "The pattern acts much like a shell wildcard / glob pattern, except that slashes are not treated specially, so that `a*b` matches both `accb` and `ac/cb`, and `a[bc/]*` matches all of `a/d`, `abcd`, `ac/cb`, and `accb`."

Examples:

```
$ git branch -a
  a/d
  abcd
  ac/cb
  accb
* master
$ git branch --list 'a*b'
  ac/cb
  accb
$ git branch --list 'a[bc/]*'
  a/d
  abcd
  ac/cb
  accb
$
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass a negation pattern?

Comment: @mljrg: no. For complex operations, use `git for-each-ref` and write a script.

Comment: @mljrg: torek et al's answer suggests a type of negation to try and in fact it works.  You can negate on a per character position basis.  For example to list all not "old/" branches you can specify `git branch --list '[^o]*' 'o[^l]*' 'ol[^d]*' 'old[^/]*' 'o' 'ol' 'old'`.  That is extremely cumbersome to get exactly what you want, but if you need a pattern more than once you can set it as an alias.  Tested in git 2.37.1.  Sure wish they had supported .gitignore syntax with its `!` option.

Comment: @SensorSmith: Yes, that's why I just summarized it as "no". (I've done this sort of thing with glob patterns in shells before, it's just too painful to use in practice...)