# Filter Regex matched git branches to build on Jenkins + Windows with webhook

Tags: windows, powershell, github, jenkins

I have Jenkins installation (v2.332.2) on windows (AWS) with git plugin and GitHub webhook trigger.

When I hardcode the values of branches such as dd.d or dd.* the webhook triggers build appropriately. I want to be able to build all branches that match a certain pattern for branch names.

E.g.,

1. origin/18.3
2. origin/22.1
3. origin/22.0
4. origin/29.0
5. origin/33.2
6. origin/22.1-release (I don't want to build)
7. origin/20.3-s36834 (I don't want to build)

I have tried to add the regex in branch specifications multiple ways but to no avail.
any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried the following combinations for branches regex

1. origin/\d{2}.\d{2}$
2. origin/\d+.\d+$
3. \d{2}.\d{2}$
4. \d+.\d+$
5. origin/\d{2}*
6. \d{2}*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The branch specifier in your screenshot looks more like a _wildcard_ pattern than a regex - are you sure that regexes are supported?

Comment: It is propably a git _branch pattern_, which is similar to a _shell wildcard_, but has some differences, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41403591/7571258).

Comment: @mklement0 that's just the latest screenshot with my hardcoded value for the branch name that worked. It worked for 2* 22.* etc but the moment I specify anything regex, it doesn't get triggered. Those are the regex combination I mentioned above

Comment: But for my requirements, I think world cards will not suffice. That is my make-shift solution for now

Comment: A comment below the linked answer suggests you can use negation, e. g. `origin/*.*[^-]` which would exclude branches with a hyphen like `origin/22.1-release`.

Comment: @zett42: I'm no Jenkins expert, but it appears that Jenkins really does use regex here. (Git is not relevant, it's what Jenkins does that matters.) See, e.g., [How to exclude git branch from building in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21314632/1256452).

Comment: Thanks, @torek. Judging by one of the answers to the linked question and https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58804, use of regexes requires _opt-in_, by _prefixing the regex with `:`_.