# Why does git remote prune origin remove my local tags?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have several tags that reference commits from local branches and remote tracking branches, or ancestors of those commits.

I want to remove references to branches and tags on `origin` after having run `git fetch`:

`git remote prune origin --dry-run`

But the output indicates it would prune my local tags, even ones that were created manually by me instead of being `fetch`ed from any remote:

```
 * [would prune] origin/git-svn
 * [would prune] origin/ignore/some_branch
 * [would prune] refs/tags/MyLocalTag
 * [would prune] refs/tags/MyLocalTag2
```

Why is git trying to prune my local tags (even those that point to my local branches with no upstream)?

Comment: Where are your local tags? I mean, in what branches? 
According doc, "git-prune - Prune all unreachable objects from the object database", so git thinks that those tags are unreachable..

Comment: @mayo: The local branches whose HEADs I created the tags from have been deleted via `git checkout -D`. They're just under refs/tags, not origin/. I am not using `git prune`, I'm using `git remote prune` which "Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under <name>. These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by <name>, but are still locally available in 'remotes/<name>'."

Comment: Any idea on how to recover lost tags after them being pruned? I didn't realize tags would be pruned along with branches and ran the command without `--dry-run` directly. :( The logged output only lists the removed tags but not the commits they were associated with, which would have allowed me to recover manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this again and narrowed the problem down to the `remote.origin.fetch` config. I had added a refspec to ensure that `git fetch` fetched all tags from the remote:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://<path-to-repo>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

As far as I can tell, this works much like setting `tagopt = --tags`, in that running `git fetch origin` will copy all tags into `.git/refs/tags`. However, **including this refspec in the config file has the unexpected side effect of causing `git remote prune origin` to prune all local tags**.

I submitted [a bug report](https://public-inbox.org/git/CACi5S_39wNrbfjLfn0xhCY+uewtFN2YmnAcRc86z6pjUTjWPHQ@mail.gmail.com/) which has been met with a series of patches to better explain this in the documentation, as well as (ironically) new flags to specifically enable this behavior of removing tags without needing the extra refspec in the remote's fetch config.

Comment: Nice feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

Since [Git 2.17 (Q2 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215190/6309), `git config fetch.pruneTags false` can help.

See:

- [`git config fetch.pruneTags`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-fetchprune)
- [`git fetch` # pruning](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_pruning)

It should be false by default:

> Git has a default disposition of keeping data unless it’s explicitly thrown away; this extends to holding onto local references to branches on remotes that have themselves deleted those branches.

---

Try instead (2016)

- [pushing your tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2988088/6309)

  ```
  git push --tags
  ```
- fetching with prune:

  ```
  git fetch --prune --tags origin
  ```

[`git fetch` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) mentions:

> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote.
>   **Tags are not subject to pruning if they are fetched only because of the default tag auto-following or due to a `--tags` option**.

If anything goes wrong, remember [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to recover any tag incorrectly removed.

---

The OP adds:

> Unfortunately I don't have the ability to push to the repo. But I don't need the tags to be associated with the upstream (origin);

You could push then to a fork or any clone --mirror copy of the original repo. My point is to push them to some back repo.

> why can't I just have a tag pointing to a local branch that doesn't get removed on git remote prune origin?

They should not be removed indeed (see next point)

> Makes me think somehow I'm creating the tags wrong (`git tag foo MyLocalBranch`).

That is it! You have created [**lightweight tags**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Lightweight-Tags), which linked to the branch, as opposed to [**annotated tags**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Annotated-Tags), which would reference the branch HEAD commit.

Try creating tags as:

```
git tag -m "old MyLocalBranch" foo MyLocalBranch
```

Adding a comment is enough to create an annotated tag, separate from the branch: they won't be removed by a `git remote prune origin` (check with `--dry-run` first), or with `git fetch --prune --tags` (but only if those tags were pushed first).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to push to the repo. But I don't need the tags to be associated with the upstream (`origin`); why can't I just have a tag pointing to a local branch that doesn't get removed on `git remote prune origin`? Makes me think somehow I'm creating the tags wrong (`git tag foo MyLocalBranch`).

Comment: @mgiuffrida I have edited the answer and pointed out the correct way to create a tag which will resist to a `git remote prune origin`

Comment: I can't reproduce my own description anymore after having done the initial problematic prune. I'm still unclear why lightweight tags would be pruned if they consist of a checksum (of an otherwise unreachable commit). I must be misinterpreting what happened. I'm closing the question but still awarded you the bounty.

Comment: @mgiuffrida They (lightweight tags) would be pruned because the branches they are attached to would be prune.

Comment: The tags don't necessarily point to branches, this happens when they point to local commits too. And `git remote prune origin` does also remove annotated tags, having just tested this.

Comment: @mgiuffrida interesting: I'll have to test again https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html#git-remote-empruneem

Comment: I think I identified the root cause: my `remote.origin.fetch` config included a refspec meant to fetch tags, `+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`. Only when this line is present does `git remote prune origin` remove local tags. (Instead of the refspec, I can set `remote.origin.tagopt == --tags` for the desired effect.)

Comment: @VonC , why would `git remote prune origin` depending on `remote.origin.fetch` ? Why is this thing not mentioned in doc ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin Not sure. I see this in the sources: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/remote.c#L151-L155

Answer (score 0):

As of git 2.17, there is a [`fetch.pruneTags` config setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_pruning). Mine was set to `true`, and setting it to `false` fixes my local tag loss issues.