# git fetch --prune origin <refspec>

Tags: git

I thought `git fetch --prune origin <refspec>` does the following

a) prune stale remote tracking branches

b) then do the fetching as `git fetch origin <refpec>` do

but reading the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch/2.18.0#_pruning) ,

`git fetch --prune origin refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` does not behave like above.
So , pruning behaviour depends on refspec.

How will pruning with fetch behave with respect to refspec passed ?
I am using git **2.18**

**EDIT : Adding more observations that I saw :**

My `remote.origin.fetch` = `remote.origin.fetch=refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

[Why am I mentioning it ? Because of this strange relation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48260726/2844702)

**Case 1 :** `git fetch --prune --dry-run origin`

This prunes the remote tracking branches not present in remote repository. Then fetches like `git fetch --dry-run origin`

**Case 2 :** `git fetch --prune --dry-run origin refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

This first **deletes all** my remote tracking branches ( note here that `jk` needed pruning and is not recreated) and then creates them again and then update them. Strange !! Here is sample :

```
- [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/holo
- [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/ioio
- [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/jj
- [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/jkkk
- [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/jk
* [new branch]      holo       -> holo
* [new branch]      ioio       -> ioio
* [new branch]      jj         -> jj
* [new branch]      jk         -> jkkk
= [up to date]      holo       -> origin/holo
= [up to date]      ioio       -> origin/ioio
= [up to date]      jj         -> origin/jj
= [up to date]      jkkk       -> origin/jkkk
```

**Case 3 :** `git fetch --prune --dry-run origin master` or `git fetch --prune --dry-run origin master:master`

Prunes nothing (Master existed on remote repo too but there were remote tracking branches in my local that needed pruning but it did not touched it ). After that behaves like `git fetch --dry-run origin master`

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
```

**Case 4 :** `git fetch --prune --dry-run origin refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`

This just prunes tags first and then behave like `git fetch --dry-run origin refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`

**Case 5 :** `git fetch origin --prune --verbose --dry-run master:refs/remotes/origin/kk`

(Assuming `kk` branch does not exist on remote repo anymore)

This firsts deletes `refs/remotes/origin/kk` and then recreates it and updates.

```
 - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/kk
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/kk
 = [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
```

So, Case 1 and Case 4 are what I thought it should behave as explained in starting of my question. Case 2 , Case 3 and Case 5 did not followed the pattern. So what should I conclude then ? How will pruning with fetch behave with respect to refspec passed ? Any common pattern among all that we can explain the behaviour by ?

Comment: I have not tried this and would not recommend doing this widely anyway (different Git versions have had different implementations of the `--prune` code, with different corner-case bugs) but it seems likely that the `--refmap` option will affect the way `--prune` works, so you could try that.

Comment: If you want to just think about the problem (and then work on Git itself and/or submit patches to the Git folks), the basic issue here is that in the v0 transfer protocol, we start by doing `git ls-remote` and getting *all* the references from the other Git, which enables the prune ability: we can see how *all* their references will be mapped into our references. The rest is merely a matter of programming. However, the new v2 transfer protocol deliberately *avoids* getting all the references from the other Git, which will affect our ability to do `--prune` at all.