# Vulcan.js with git bash on windows using powershell

Tags: windows, bash, git, meteor

I am using *bash on Ubuntu on windows*, I open powershell and the run command `bash` I navigate to the Vulcan-starter [repo](https://github.com/VulcanJS/Vulcan-Starter) I cloned. It is a Meteor project. I have installed meteor using the curl command as recommended on Meteor's website. I am using node version 8.11.1 I run `npm install` and everything installs fine, when I run `npm start` this is where I get the errors. Here is the error below, and a more detailed log is included in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anderskitson/bc6d853ac35e2e84c27ea7e3e102db09).

```
MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
This can be caused by MongoDB being unable to write to a local database.
Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. MongoDB does
not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 254
npm ERR! Vulcan@1.8.11 start: `meteor --settings settings.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 254
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Vulcan@1.8.11 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/anderskitson/.npm/_logs/2018-03-30T21_21_54_469Z-debug.log
```

Comment: bash on Ubuntu (through WSL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) and Git bash (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases, Git for Windows, called by your Powershell session) are two different environments, are they not?

Comment: hmm, I guess they are. I am also using a terminal called hyper.is and I have this setting `shell: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe',` is that my git bash then? or The ubuntu bash. I thought for some reason that installing ubuntu bash would allow me to run it under hyper terminal or the terminal in visual studio code.

Comment: I can assure you they are *very* different (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309). Don't use anything fro System32 though. Use only a simplified PATH (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688159/6309)

Comment: the WSL git bash would be in the WSL filesystem, which is: https://askubuntu.com/a/759885/5470

Comment: well, when I use the `bash on ubuntu windows` I can run `nvm` which is a node version manager. I installed it in powershell after typing bash and then installing `nvm` via curl. So how is it that `bash on ubuntu windows` can see `nvm` when I never installed it there directly, I just ran `bash` in powershell and installed `nvm` I am not typing `git bash` I am just typing `bash`

Comment: `bash` is enough indeed. You just need to make sure *which* `bash` is used. I know nothing of one in `Windows\System32`, hence my suggestion to use a simplified `PATH` (for testing purpose)