# .gitattributes file is added for line breaks

Tags: git, teamcity, tortoisegit

I am using Github and TeamCity.
The line breaks of `txt` files don't exist after committing them to `Github`,
what can I do in order to keep these line breaks in txt files?

When I am using `notepad++` to view these files- the line-breaks appear, 
but when using `Windows notepad` there are no line breaks.

I googled for a solution and I found that if add a new file in the root directory
`.gitattributes` that will contain:

```
*.txt crlf
```

tried also

```
*.txt eol=crlf
```

it will solve the problem, so I committed it to Github and then tried to download the txt file again, but it still don't show the line breaks.

What else can be done? how can I be certain that Github is using the `.gitattributes` that I added? cause it don't seem to use it.

---

To solve that issue I ended up adding `.gitattributes` file to the root folder of the project with this content:

```
# Windows-only files
*.txt text eol=crlf
```

But this only handle the problem in Github, I use `Github` and also `TeamCity` 
So when I downloaded the text file through `TeamCity`, the file EOL was not set to `CRLF`
in `TeamCity` this checkbox need to be checked also (its in the VCS):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580886/6309), with Git 2.16 or more, you can do, on your local repo, where you have added or pulled the `.gitattributes` file:

```
git add --renormalize .
git commit -m "Introduce end-of-line normalization"
```

You can test it using the [latest portable Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (like [`PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.17.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe)), and using a [simplified PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688159/6309).

This is simpler than trying to do the same with TortoiseGit for now.

---

If everything still fails locally, some tool must change the file content, and that is what the OP has found: here, TeamCity didn't have the proper option selected.

Comment: can i achieve it, using TortoiseGit?

Comment: @E.Meir No: if you are on Windows, just unciompress https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.17.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.17.0-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want, add it to your PATH and you are good to go. No setup required.

Comment: yes. i am on windows- and then via CMD, enter the lines you suggested ?

Comment: @E.Meir yes, provided `git version` returns 2.16 or more, and that you are within your cloned repo folder. Then ush back to github.

Comment: I uncompressed it, what should i add to the Path variable?

Comment: @E.Meir Just for testing, you can enter what I mention in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47688159/6309: no need to modify your User environment variables just yet.

Comment: @E.Meir you should then push back To GitHub your new commit (check first with git log: you should see a new commit.

Comment: @E.Meir Can you give an example of a file with no newlines on your GitHub repo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169057/discussion-between-e-meir-and-vonc).

Comment: @E.Meir Good catch. I have updated the answer to reflect that possibility.