# list remote tags which are not available in my local repo?

Tags: git

I need to do the following in git.

a) list all the newly created annotated tags in remote (which are not present in my local repo)

b) switch to that tag one by one and do some operations like build, code review etc

What is the command to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no single command that does what you asked.

```
git show-ref --tags -d              // lists local tags, including dereferences
git ls-remote --tags <repository>   // lists tags on remote
git checkout <tag>                  // switch to branch at tag
```

I believe annotated tags correspond to refs with `^{}` appended (as they are dereferenced), this might help you concoct a diff script to list all new annotated tags.

The discussion in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841341/remove-local-tags-that-are-no-longer-on-the-remote-repository) might also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a fetch, `.git/FETCH_HEAD` lists every reference that was retrieved, so `git fetch`*`remote`* and run through the tags listed in that file.