# git tag -l does not remove deleted tags

Tags: git, tags

This is the scenario

I cloned my repository to a directory which I regularly update by

```
git pull
```

Now I created one more directory and checked out same repository

I had to create some tags, but by mistake I created tags with wrong name
so I deleted tags from the first directory

```
git tag -d old
git push origin :refs/tags/old
git push --tags
```

If from second directory I am trying

```
git tag -l
```

I am not able to get synchronised information as tag does not get deleted from list

Then I did

```
git pull --tags
```

Added tags get reflected but deleted tags does not get deleted.

```
git pull origin --tags
```

No change to result

How can I get synchronised list so that tags deleted are also reflected in other directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove local tags that are no longer on the remote repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841341/remove-local-tags-that-are-no-longer-on-the-remote-repository)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will delete any local tags that are not on the remote.

```
git fetch origin refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* --prune
```

In order to fetch tags automatically, add the following line to your `.git/config` file under the entry for `[remote "origin"]`.

```
fetch = refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Comment: Thanks @Joseph K. Strauss. first command does the trick. But for the second I do not have fetch = refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* under my remote can I add it by any command, without editing .git/config