# Git tags are showing even though I deleted them

Tags: git

I have deleted some tags by running:

1. `git tag -d TAGNAME`
2. `git push origin :refs/tags/TAGNAME`

After that I asked all team members to run:

1. `git tag -d $(git tag)` - to remove all local tags
2. `git fetch --tags` - to retrieve current tags from remote.

The problem is that now and then I see the old tags appearing again.
I suspect that someone still has a few old tags and didn't delete them or pulled before I deleted or so.

Is there a way to completely delete a tag?

For example - to make a commit that deletes old tags and so before users will be able to push they will have to pull that commit and so it will change their tags. Is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

When you delete remote branches, you have to [`git remote prune origin`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) in order to completely remove these deleted branches from the working copy.

Since tags are quite much the same as branches, I assume you need to prune here too.

[`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) also knows the `--prune` parameter, so either

```
git remote prune origin
```

or

```
git fetch --prune
```

should do the trick.

This is an additional safety measure: `fetch` only updates known remote branches and introduces new ones but never deletes them unless `--prune` is requested.

Answer (score 6):

The solution from @eckes did not work for me; what did work was this answer from Joseph K Strauss:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782368/15382340

```
git fetch origin refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* --prune
```