# Submodule tags are not updated with git submodule repository URL update

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-tag

I have to update the repo URL of a submodule used in my main repo. These are the steps I've followed.

1) Modify the repo URL in `.gitmodules` file.

2) Run `git submodule sync` (Then `.git/config` got updated with the new URL)

3) Then i executed the below command:

```
git submodule update --init --remote -- <path-to-submodule-folder>
```

After this i got the submodule files updated from the new repo URL. But in `.git/modules/<path-to-submodule-folder>/packed-refs` file the tags are still of the previous repo only.

For example:

packed-refs before submodule and after submodule are same like below (which are the tags fetched from the previous repo URL):

```
208058b9ad3fd54caf66a9c9972cfe80d4f4bc13 refs/tags/3.3.3
3dc3a0ea2d0773af4c0ffd7bbcb21c608e28fcef refs/tags/3.3.4
81bdde705cc69776fd63c870581ee0c793d48873 refs/tags/3.3.5
f8d653d1f9329081e017caf6cb9341834a71b6d2 refs/tags/3.3.6
21ae2afd4edaa1b69782c67a54182d34efe43f9c refs/tags/3.3.7
```

Ideally i should get new tags in packed-refs file after the submodule is updated so that i can checkout to a specific tag in the new repo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See if you can get those tags by going to the updated submodule subfolder, and do a `git fetch --tags`

See "[Does “git fetch --tags” include “git fetch”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608181/6309)". A `git fetch` alone (done by the `git submodule update --remote`) would not fetch tags by default.

Comment: I did `git fetch --tags`. It updated the tags of the submodule. Now i'm able to checkout to a specific tag in the new repo of submodule. Half of my problem is solved. But the `packed-refs` file of the submodule is still showing commit ids of the previous repo.

Comment: @manishreddy Would a `git fetch <remote> --prune --tags` be enough? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311126/6309)