# Azure DevOps REST Api Tags call (Repos > Tags)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a `Repos Tags` REST Api call to get the data from this page? (Repos > Tags)

[image]

It would be awesome if it also includes `CREATE`, `PATCH` and `DELETE`.

The tab it self use [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_git/{repo}/tags?__rt=fps&__ver=2](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_git/%7Brepo%7D/tags?__rt=fps&__ver=2)
which I interpret as a bad sign.

---

#### EDIT 1: Create a Tag

**Create**: the `Create Tag` button use: [Annotated Tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated%20tags?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

So what is missing in this REST Api call is a `LIST` to get the `{objectId}` of the elements.

---

#### EDIT 2: List & Delete Tags

**List**: To list all Tags `objectId`, I found out that you can use [Refs - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

**Delete**: I think this call is complete undocumented. But you can comprehend that the TFS use the following payload to do this job:

```
var json = {
    name: `refs/tags/${xName}`,
    newObjectId: '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    oldObjectId: xObjectId
};
var payload = [json];
```

Post this `payload` to [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?api-version=5.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7BrepositoryId%7D/refs?api-version=5.1)

---

#### EDIT 3: behavior on git client side

The only way I found to update the `git tags` on client side is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841341/remove-local-git-tags-that-are-no-longer-on-the-remote-repository):

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
git fetch --tags
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.**To create Tags:** [Create/Get tag apis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/annotated%20tags?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Create tag:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/annotatedtags?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Get tag:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/annotatedtags/{objectId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

2.**To list Tags:** We don't have "Annotated Tags-List", but we have [Refs-tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#refs-tags) which does similar job. (Hint from **Mar Tin**, thanks to him!)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/refs?filter=tags/&api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

3.**To delete the tag(Fetch it from F12):**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{RepoName}/refs?api-version=5.1
```

Request Body(Don't forget the `[` and `]`,it's necessary when testing in PostMan):

```
 [{
    "name": "refs/tags/{TagName}",
    "newObjectId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "oldObjectId": "{OldObjectID}"
 }]
```

**Note:** All the info about `ObjectID` can be fetched via `Refs-tags` api in tip2.

> For your question about whether the tag is really deleted or is it
> only moved to a sneaky archive.

You're see this when trying to delete the Tag via the Delete tag button in web portal:

[image]

And the corresponding request I fetched from Edge(F12) is:

[image]

So the tag will be **permanently** deleted, it's not just moved to a sneaky archive.

Comment: Thanks for your response Lance. Could you tell me what exactly happen on TFS when a tag get deleted by a `ref post newObjectId: '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'` is the tag really deleted or is it only moved to a sneaky archive?

Comment: @MarTin It's really deleted and it's permanently deleted! Calling the Update refs api with `ref post newObjectId: '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` has the same function of the Delete Tag button(GUI). And as the warning states, the tag will be really deleted!

Comment: @MarTin You can get more details from the update2 above. And since you issue has been resolved, would you please add a answer with details to answer your own question? So that members with similar issue could benefit from that! Or you can feel free to edit my answer to add other details, thx~