# How to list all tags along with the full message in git?

Tags: git, tags, git-tag

I want git to list all tags along with the full annotation or commit message. Something like this is close:

```
git tag -n5
```

This does exactly what I want except that it will only show up to the first 5 lines of the tag message.

I guess I can just use a very large number. What is the highest number I can use here? Is it the same on every computer?

**UPDATE**: I have had much time to think about this, and now I think I don't necessarily want to show the entirety of each message if some of them are extraordinarily long. I didn't really have any particular need that required me to see massive messages (other than my own propensity to be long winded in everything I write, including tag messages). I just didn't like the idea that it was not necessarily going to show me the whole message, as that made me feel like it was hiding information from me. But too much information can also be a bad thing.

Comment: `git tag -n` did it for me

Comment: `git tag -n` only prints the first line of the annotation, according to the manpage.

Comment: @INTPner, agreed, -l tag is used for listing tags with a specific pattern. Editing the answer.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

```
git tag -n99
```

Short and sweet. This will list up to 99 lines from each tag annotation/commit message. [Here is a link to the official documentation for git tag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag).

I now think the limitation of only showing up to 99 lines per tag is actually a good thing as most of the time, if there were really more than 99 lines for a single tag, you wouldn't really want to see all the rest of the lines would you? If you did want to see more than 99 lines per tag, you could always increase this to a larger number.

I mean, I guess there could be a specific situation or reason to want to see massive tag messages, but at what point do you **not** want to see the whole message? When it has more than 999 lines? 10,000? 1,000,000? My point is, it typically makes sense to have a cap on how many lines you would see, and this number allows you to set that.

Since I am making an argument for what you generally want to see when looking at your tags, it probably makes sense to set something like this as an alias (from Iulian Onofrei's comment below):

`git config --global alias.tags 'tag -n99'`

I mean, you don't really want to have to type in `git tag -n99` every time you just want to see your tags do you? Once that alias is configured, whenever you want to see your tags, you would just type `git tags` into your terminal. Personally, I prefer to take things a step further than this and create even more abbreviated bash aliases for all my commonly used commands. For that purpose, you could add something like this to your .bashrc file (works on Linux and similar environments):

`alias gtag='git tag -n99'`

Then whenever you want to see your tags, you just type `gtag`. Another advantage of going down the alias path (either git aliases or bash aliases or whatever) is you now have a spot already in place where you can add further customizations to how you personally, generally want to have your tags shown to you (like sorting them in certain ways as in my comment below, etc). Once you get over the hurtle of creating your first alias, you will now realize how easy it is to create more of them for other things you like to work in a customized way, like `git log`, but let's save that one for a different question/answer.

Comment: `git config --global alias.tags 'tag -n99'`

Comment: @IulianOnofrei, nice, I didn't know git allowed you to define aliases. I realize this is off topic, but I can't resist. This is what I am now using (placed in your .bashrc or something like that): `alias gtag='git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short) %(taggerdate) %(subject) %(body)" refs/tags | sort -V'`

Answer (score 480):

Try this it will list all the tags along with annotations & 9 lines of message for every tag:

```
git tag -n9
```

can also use

```
git tag -l -n9
```

if specific tags are to list:

```
git tag -l -n9 'v3.*'
```

(e.g, above command will only display tags starting with "v3.", the v3.* should around with single quote)

-l , --list 
List tags with names that match the given pattern (or all if no pattern is given).
Running "git tag" without arguments also lists all tags. The pattern is a shell wildcard
(i.e., matched using fnmatch(3)). Multiple patterns may be given; if any of them
matches, the tag is shown.

Comment: This will only print the first line of each annotation.

Comment: @Paul Price: only you have an annotation, otherwise it prints the commit message. Agree this is not *the* answer.

Comment: The `-n` flag corresponds to the number of lines you want to have printed. Sadly the output isn't great so perhaps the `--column` flag would be best to output messages cleanly.

Comment: According to the documentation, the `-l` option is to filter on a pattern. I don't see how that would be helpful here. Am I missing something?

Comment: @INTPnerd yes, the `-l` is totally superfluous here

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 if you try running without -l, you'll get fatal: -n option is only allowed with -l.

Comment: @P.MyerNore You must be using a weird version of git or passing additional arguments to do something more than what this question is asking. But it is good to know that for certain situations the -l is needed.

Comment: My favorite command: list up to 99 lines for each tag, listing only tags which contain string "my string" somewhere in them: `git tag -l -n99 '*my string*'`

Answer (score 28):

[Mark Longair's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5358630/834250) (using `git show`) is close to what is desired in the question.  However, it also includes the commit pointed at by the tag, along with the full patch for that commit.  Since the commit can be somewhat unrelated to the tag (it's only one commit that the tag is attempting to capture), this may be undesirable.  I believe the following is a bit nicer:

```
for t in `git tag -l`; do git cat-file -p `git rev-parse $t`; done
```

Comment: Mark's git show did not show patches for my usage. His command omits -p or --patch, but to be totally sure of skipping the diff, one can use: --no-patch. (on git v2.7.1/mac)

Comment: this is safer for scripting as it uses plumming

Answer (score 17):

Use --format option

```
git tag -l --format='%(tag) %(subject)'
```

Answer (score 15):

It's far from pretty, but you could create a script or an alias that does something like this:

```
for c in $(git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format='%(refname)'); do echo $c; git show --quiet "$c"; echo; done
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to replace `git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format='%(refname)'` with `git tag -l`?

Comment: @ShaiBerger: in practice, I don't think so - I guess I was just thinking that `git tag` is porcelain and `git for-each-ref` is plumbing, so the output of the latter should be more stable for scripting.

Comment: Based on this answer, I used git log instead of git show to get a prettier result: `for c in $(git tag -l); do git tag -l -n1 $c; echo Commit message: \`git log -n1 --format=%B --quiet "$c"\`; echo; done`

Answer (score 12):

Last tag message only:

```
git cat-file -p $(git rev-parse $(git tag -l | tail -n1)) | tail -n +6
```

Comment: For anyone else happening upon this from google: If you want to show the message from a particular tag:

`git cat-file -p <tag> | tail -n +6`

Answer (score 8):

You can show messages of tags with this command

```
git tag -n
```

-n option for show message.

Answer (score 7):

```
git tag -l --format='%(contents)'
```

or

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format='%(contents)'
```

will output full annotation message for every tag (including signature if its signed).

- `%(contents:subject)` will output only first line
- `%(contents:body)` will output annotation without first line and signature (useful text only)
- `%(contents:signature)` will output only PGP-signature

See more in [`man git-for-each-ref` “Field names” section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names).

Comment: If you want to include the tag as well you could use:
`git tag -l --format='%(tag): %(contents)' `

Comment: Even better, `git tag -l --format="%(tag)"$'\n'"%(contents)"`

Answer (score 2):

I prefer doing this on the command line, but if you don't mind a web interface and you use GitHub, you can visit `https://github.com/user/repo/tags` and click on the "..." next to each tag to display its annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Below command may provide more related info on tags

```
git tag --format='%(refname:strip=2)%09%(creatordate:short)%09%(authorname)%09%(subject)' --sort=-creatordate
```

Result lists tag, date, name, oneline:

```
R7.0 2023-06-28  John Doe  [APP]Modified for release
R6.5 2023-04-02  John Doe  [APP]Updated readme
```

To get full message, change *subject* in the command to *contents*.

The format is in '%(fieldname)'. For example, '%09' is '\t', '%0a' is '\n', %(color:red), etc. Details see

```
git help for-each-ref
```