# How to get all local and remote tags in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-bash, git-tag

I want to view all local and remote tags.

To view all local and remote branches I use:

```
git branch -a
```

Which shows my local branches in white, current branch in green and remote (origin) branches in red.

However `-a` for `git tag` is used for create a tag with an annotation or message.

What is the tag equivalent of `git branch -a` to display all local and origin tags?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358336/have-git-list-all-tags-along-with-the-full-message and see if it gives you what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, sync your tags with the remote repository by :

```
git fetch --tags
```

Then, you can use `git tag` to list tags of your repository.

You can also use `git tag -l`. But if you use the `-l` option, you can pass a search pattern to filter out tags.

Answer (score 4):

You can list all refs in any repo you've got a url or path or remote name for with

```
git ls-remote u://r/l           # or path, or remote name
```

and [there's options to limit what's listed](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote).

Answer (score 1):

First of all do a full fetch

```
# fetch (update local branch) with all tags branches and 
# the --prune will remove the 
git fetch --all --prune
```

> ***`git fetch`***
>
> Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete their histories.
>
> ***`--all`***
>   Fetch all remotes.

---

#### How to list all tags?

***`git tag -l`***

> ***`-l / --list <pattern> /***`
>
> List tags with names that match the given pattern (or **all** if no pattern is given).
>
> **Running "git tag" without arguments also lists all tags.**
>
> The pattern is a shell wildcard (i.e., matched using fnmatch(3)). Multiple patterns may be given; if any of them matches, the tag is shown.