# Git: committing to a tag and then merging commit to master

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-tag

I'm mainly familiar with SVN. I have been using Git for a while, but haven't done things that are extremely advanced. For my project, I have been creating tags that mark individual releases. For example, I have a tag called `v1.2.3` for a particular release of my project. I want to commit a bugfix to that tag and then merge that into master. How do I go about doing that? I looked up information about creating a branch from a tag, but I am not sure if that's the right way of doing it. Can I commit directly to a tag and then merge it into master?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename a tag in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028649/rename-a-tag-in-git)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Committing to a tag is entirely wrong, in my opinion, although svn, by design allows it.

Say, you have a release v1.2.3 and you commit to that tag - you get what? Still v1.2.3 or 1.2.3a or something like that? How do you recover what version 1.2.3 was later on?

Nevertheless, in git you can recreate tags. But I am not sure if you should do that for any other case than "I accidentally tagged the wrong version" or in case you have "moving" tags like "last stable revision".

In git you could do:

```
git branch v1.2.3-bugfix v1.2.3   [v1.2.3-bugfix is your branch, v1.2.3 the tag]
git checkout v1.2.3-bugfix
-- do your changes --
git add ...
git commit
git tag -f v1.2.3
```

That is, first you create a branch starting from your tag.
Then you check out that branch (there is shortcut for that via git checkout -b). You commit your changes and re-create the tag.

Afterwards, you could delete your bugfix-branch.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I was on the right track. That's basically what I initially wanted to do (create a branch off a tag, commit to it, and then retag). I just wasn't sure if that was the "git way" of doing it.

Comment: That is not the git way! A tag in git is something that will definitely **never** change. Like the v1.3 release – once it’s released nothing will ever change which version you released. What you are looking for is a branch to track the maintenance of a specific release.

Comment: @Chronial That's how it is supposed to be, in my opinion, no matter if you are using svn, cvs, git, perforce or whatever - at least for release tags once they are published. Everything else will create confusion later on.

Comment: @sstn that’s a good point, but unlike svn git does actually enforce this harshly. If you follow sstn’s advice, everybody else wiil get a tag conflict on pulling and you will have to contact all the others devs and tell them to overwrite their local tag with your new one.

Comment: @Chronial I was curious and tested it. `git fetch --tags` will actually seamlessly update tags. I must admit that this suprised me. I consider the approach wrong, but in some workflows it may make sense, e.g. if you have moving tags like master-int-tests-passed to mark the last revision which passed tests or something like that... although I would probably choose another approach for that.

Comment: @sstn ok – that’s indeed surprising. The git manual claims the opposite: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_re_tagging

Comment: the git manual says "**If you never pushed anything out**, just re-tag it."