# “tag already exists in the remote" error after recreating the git tag

Tags: git, repository, git-tag

I get the following error after I run the steps below:

```
To git@provider.com:username/repo-name.git
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (already exists)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@provider.com:username/repo-name.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.
```

1. Created the repository
2. Cloned the repo on the local machine.
3. Modified the README file, commited the changes and pushed the commit.
4. Created tag `dev`: `git tag dev`
5. Pushed tags: `git push --tags`
6. Modified the README file, commited the changes and pushed the commit.
7. Deleted tag `dev` , created it again and pushed tags:

   ```
   git tag -d dev
   git tag dev
   git push --tags
   ```

Why is this happening?

I am on Mac. My friends that use Linux (Ubuntu) don't have this problem. I know that I can use `git push --tags -f` to force the tag update, but this is dangerous (e.g. rewriting a commit made by mistake only in the tag, not in the branch).

Comment: Commits are not done "in tags" or "in branches" (although it sure feels like the latter is the case).  In fact, tag and branch names simply *point to* (one, single) commit.  See answer below.

Comment: this worked for me `git pull --tags` then `git push origin --tags`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929667/updates-were-rejected-because-the-tag-already-exists-when-attempting-to-push-i

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Edit, 24 Nov 2016: this answer is apparently popular, so I am adding a note here.  If you *replace* a tag on a central server, anyone who has the *old* tag—any clone of that central-server repository that already has the tag—could *retain its old tag*.  So while this tells you how to do it, be really sure you *want* to do it.  You'll need to get everyone who already has the "wrong" tag to delete *their* "wrong tag" and replace it with the new "right tag".

Testing in Git 2.10/2.11 shows that retaining the old tag is the default behavior for clients running `git fetch`, and updating is the default behavior for clients running `git fetch --tags`.

(Original answer follows.)

---

When you ask to push tags, `git push --tags` sends (along with any commits and other objects needed and any other ref updates from the push settings) to the remote an update request of the form `new-sha1 refs/tags/name`.  (Well, it sends however many: one of those for each tag.)

The update request is modified by the remote to add an *`old-sha1`* (or again, one for each tag), then delivered to the pre-receive and/or update hooks (whichever hooks exist on the remote).  Those hooks can decide whether to allow or reject the tag create/delete/update.

The *`old-sha1`* value is the all-zeros "null" SHA-1 if the tag is being created.  The *`new-sha1`* is the null SHA-1 if the tag is being deleted.  Otherwise both SHA-1 values are real, valid values.

Even with no hooks, there's a sort of "built-in hook" that is also run: the remote will refuse to move a tag unless you use the "force" flag (though the "built-in hook" is always OK with both "add" and "delete").  The rejection message you're seeing is coming from this built-in hook.  (Incidentally, this same built-in hook also rejects branch updates that are not fast-forwards.)<sup>1</sup>

But—here's one of the keys to understanding what's going on—the `git push` step has no idea whether the remote has that tag now, and if so, what SHA-1 value it has.  It only says "here's my complete list of tags, along with their SHA-1 values".  The remote compares the values and if there are additions and/or changes, runs the hooks on those.  (For tags that are the same, it does nothing at all.  For tags you don't have that they do, it also does nothing!)

If you delete the tag locally, then `push`, your push simply does not transfer the tag.  The remote assumes no change should be made.

If you delete the tag locally, then create it pointing to a new place, then `push`, your push transfers the tag, and the remote sees this as a tag-change and rejects the change, unless it's a force-push.

Thus, you have two options:

- do a force-push, or
- delete the tag on the remote.

The latter *is* possible via `git push`<sup>2</sup> even though deleting the tag locally and `push`ing has no effect.  Assuming the name of the remote is `origin`, and the tag you want it to delete is `dev`:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/dev
```

This asks the remote to delete the tag.  The presence or absence of the tag `dev` in your local repository is irrelevant; this kind of `push`, with `:remoteref` as a refspec, is a pure-delete push.

The remote may or may not allow tag deletion (depending on any extra hooks added).  If it allows the deletion, then the tag will be gone, and a second `git push --tags`, when you have a local `dev` tag pointing to some commit or annotated tag repo object, send your new `dev` tag.  On the remote, `dev` will now be a newly created tag, so the remote will probably allow the push (again this depends on any extra hooks added).

The force-push is simpler.  If you want to be sure not to update anything *other* than the tag, just tell `git push` to push only that one refspec:

```
git push --force origin refs/tags/dev:refs/tags/dev
```

(note: you don't need `--tags` if you're explicitly pushing just one tag ref-spec).

---

<sup>1</sup>Of course, the *reason* for this built-in hook is to help enforce the behavior that other users of that same remote-repo expect: that branches are not rewound, and tags do not move.  If you force-push, you should let the other users know you are doing this, so that they can correct for it.  Note that "tags don't move at all" is newly enforced by Git 1.8.2; previous versions would allow the tag to "move forward" in the commit graph, much like branch names.  See the [git 1.8.2 release notes](http://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com/git/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt).

<sup>2</sup>It's trivial if you can log in on the remote.  Just go to the Git repository there and run `git tag -d dev`.  Note that either way—deleting the tag on the remote, or using `git push` to delete it—there's a period of time when anyone who accesses the remote will find that the `dev` tag is missing.  (They will continue to have *their own* old tag, if they already have it, and they might even push *their* old tag back up before you can push the new one.)

Comment: Is this happening only in the new versions of git? I have `1.7.9.5` and I don't have this issue...

Comment: Probalby—I have a vague memory of `git push --tags` just changing the tag automatically in older versions of git, without `--force`.  I tested this under 1.8.4 though, and you do need `--force`, or the two stage update technique.

Comment: @Johnツ: update: it's new behavior as of 1.8.2, according to the [release notes](http://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com/git/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt).  I'll edit this into footnote 1 too.

Comment: Dont know how I got into this situation, but this got a tag deleted and recreated in a trice.

Comment: how do you do a force-push if you arent a jedi?

Comment: @Fonix: same way as if you are, using `-f`, `--force`, or `+` in the refspec.

Comment: @torek Is there a way to add a `-m 'tag message'` using your force push command ?

Comment: @Danger14: no, you can only push objects existing in your own repository.  If you want some particular message (e.g., in an annotated tag) you must set that when you create the (presumably new) annotated tag.

Comment: SourceTree 1.9.x by default *retains the old tag*, but it has a "Fetch all tags" checkbox that you have to check every time you want to refresh tags.  It cannot be checked by default.

Comment: git fetch --tags fixed it for me. It said '[tag update]' and my workspace tag was updated to match the origin tag. git push says Everything up-to-date

Comment: In my case, I created a tag on github and then got this error when creating new tags on local and pushing them to origin. all I needed to do was git fetch --tags to clear up the problem.

Answer (score 62):

In Mac SourceTree only deselect the **Push all tags** checkbox:

[image]

Comment: hahahah so simple man, i was reading the accepted answer and i thought i so gonna fak this up

Comment: This is just to overcome it without actually solving the issue. This does not solve the tag name miss match at remote and local.

Comment: works for windows version as well! thanks for saving us from reading the long accepted answer that omits sourcetree users who don't care what is going on in the command prompt :)

Comment: To reiterate, to go this route isn't to "save from reading a long answer that omits sourcetree users", this is a WORKAROUND, not a SOLUTION. The accepted answer is an accepted answer because its a solution, where this workaround is going to cost you later.

Answer (score 28):

It's **quite simple** if you're using **SourceTree**.

[image]
Basically you just need to remove and re-add the conflicting tag:

1. Go to tab **Repository** -> **Tag** -> **Remove Tag**
2. Select the conflicting tag name
3. Check **Remove tag from all remotes**
4. Press **Remove**
5. Create new tag with the same name to the proper commit
6. Make sure to check **Push all tags** when pushing your changes to remote

Answer (score 25):

It seems that I'm late on this issue and/or it has already been answered, but, what could be done is:
(in my case, I had only one tag locally so.. I deleted the old tag and retagged it with:

```
git tag -d v1.0
git tag -a v1.0 -m "My commit message"
```

Then:

```
git push --tags -f
```

That will update **all** tags on remote.

**Could be dangerous! Use at own risk.**

Comment: This did it for me! The tags were only locally and not in the remote :)

Answer (score 21):

If you want to **UPDATE** a tag, let's say it `1.0.0`

1. `git checkout 1.0.0`
2. *make your changes*
3. `git ci -am 'modify some content'`
4. `git tag -f 1.0.0`
5. delete remote tag on github: `git push origin --delete 1.0.0`
6. `git push origin 1.0.0`

**DONE**

Answer (score 8):

A very simple solution - Delete all the local duplicated tags and then pull those tags from the remote. Such as:

```
git tag -d some-tag
git pull --tags
```

No more conflicts or warnings.

You may want to consider backing up your local repository ahead of time.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are getting **rejected** is that your tag lost sync with the remote version. This is the same behaviour with branches.

sync with the tag from the remote via `git pull --rebase <repo_url> +refs/tags/<TAG>` and after you sync, you need to **manage conflicts**.
If you have a diftool installed (ex. meld) `git mergetool meld` use it to sync remote and keep your changes.

The reason you're pulling with **--rebase** flag is that you want to put your work on top of the remote one so you could avoid other conflicts.

Also, what I don't understand is why would you delete the `dev` tag and re-create it??? Tags are used for specifying software versions or milestones. Example of git tags `v0.1dev`, `v0.0.1alpha`, `v2.3-cr`(cr - candidate release) and so on..

---

Another way you can solve this is issue a `git reflog` and go to the moment you pushed the `dev` tag on remote. Copy the *commit id* and `git reset --mixed <commmit_id_from_reflog>` this way you know your tag was in sync with the remote at the moment you pushed it and no conflicts will arise.

Comment: For example if you want to tag a commit that is currently in production. Would you then have to delete the old production tag from a specific commit, and create and push new tag for the commit after new production release.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows SourceTree, untick `Push all tags to remotes`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers here. Especially [the one by @torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19300065/1639345). I thought I'd add this work-around with a little explanation for those in a rush.

To summarize, what happens is that when you move a tag locally, it changes the tag from a non-Null commit value to a different value. However, because git (as a default behavior) doesn't allow changing non-Null remote tags, you can't push the change.

The work-around is to delete the tag (and tick remove all remotes). Then create the same tag and push.