# SubGit error when trying to update an SVN tag

Tags: tags, subgit

I have a SVN tag 2.14 that I'm trying to update. First, I have updated my local tag with

```
git tag 2.14 -f
```

and then I deleted the remote tag

```
git push origin :refs/tags/2.14
```

But now, when I try to push the tag with

```
git push origin refs/tags/2.14
```

I get an error saying:

```
! [rejected]    2.14 -> 2.14 (already exists)
error: failed to push some refs to ...
hint: Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote
```

I checked on the remote Git/SubGit repo with `git tag -l` and the tag still exists in the repository, but not in Subversion! I have tried to delete the tag in the SubGit repo manually with `git tag -d 2.14`, but still get the same error. When I try do a local `git fetch` with the remote tag deleted, then the remote 2.14 tag is somehow restored in the SubGit repo.

Comment: Could you please send content of your `subgit/logs` directory of your SubGit installation to support@subgit.com or to my e-mail address (in my profile)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by forcing the push with

```
git push --force origin refs/tags/2.14:refs/tags/2.14
```

As suggested in the answer to this question: [“tag already exists in the remote" error after recreating the git tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298600/tag-already-exists-in-the-remote-error-after-recreating-the-git-tag)