# "Updates were rejected because the tag already exists" when attempting to push in SourceTree

Tags: git, push, atlassian-sourcetree, git-tag

When attempting to Push via Source Tree, I get the following error:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master 
Pushing to https://user@github.com/repo.git
To https://user@github.com/repo.git
 = [up to date]      master -> master
...
 ! [rejected]        example_tag -> example_tag (already exists)
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://user@github.com/repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.
Completed with errors, see above
```

I didn't make any changes to this tag as far as I know. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

If you have not made any local changes to the tag that you want to keep, then you can **remove tag that was rejected because it *already exists*** (`example_tag` in this case):

1. Right-click the tag and choose to delete it (be sure to **uncheck** the **Remove tag from all remotes** checkbox).
2. Choose the **Fetch** option (Fetch and store all tags locally does *not* have to be enabled).
3. You should now have that tag that was just deleted back, and attempting to **Push** will no longer show that error message.

The reason this is common in SourceTree is because the **Push all tags** option is set to **on** by default. (Another way to hide this error is to uncheck that option.)

Comment: "Fetch and store all tags locally does not have to be enabled" is what did it for me, checking that just caused the problem to repeat itself.

Comment: Assuming the upstream (origin) repo is the source of truth, this solution is the least destructive, and fixes the problem instantly.

Comment: Unfortunately when you have 15 rejected tags the 1,2, and 3 steps can be very tedious.

Yes, disabling the "Push all tags" option is a probably the right way to go.

Comment: "Right-click" where? What type o IDE are you assuming?

Comment: `The reason this is common in SourceTree is because the Push all tags option is set to on by default. (Another way to hide this error is to uncheck that option.)` is exactly what I need

Answer (score 381):

You should also be able to solve this in git bash (click on "Terminal" button in the Source Tree UI).  Type:

```
git pull --tags
```

If you have conflicting tags, you can include the `-f` option in the command to override the local conflicting tags with their remote versions.

```
git pull --tags -f
```

Comment: I feel this is the best answer for it's the path of least resistance.

Comment: With a conflict you can do `git pull --tags -f` to overwrite the one you have locally if that's what you want

Comment: In SourceTree, click Fetch, and enable "fetch all tags". That would do it.

Comment: @DenLilleMand's comment should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 54):

`git pull --tags` works really well but sometimes you can get an error even with this command. Example error message:

```
 ! [rejected]        example_tag      -> example_tag  (would clobber existing tag)
```

**This can be solved with the command**: `git pull --tags -f`

`-f` stands for *force*.

Source:

https://github.com/concourse/git-resource/issues/233

Answer (score 37):

Uncheck `push all tags` at the bottom of the UI when you confirm your git push

Comment: Did you mean `push all tags`?

Comment: Great! Did not observe it. Thanks

Comment: @Wodin so if you CHECK the `push all tags` in the UI it will try to overwrite the previous tags. but you have to UNCHECK it to prevent the overwrite

Comment: @JDev-Guns I was just querying the wording. You originally said [`push all TABs`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52280040/1). I am not familiar with SourceTree, but I suspected you meant `TAGs` instead of `TABs`.

Comment: @Wodin oh gotcha! i think i said `TAGs` but if i didnt, i meant to say `TABs`

Comment: This really helped. Thanks.

Comment: But if you added a new tag locally doesn't this mean it isn't pushed to the remote?

Comment: Imo, this is the best response.

Answer (score 29):

Make sure you uncheck the "Push all tags" button while push.

[image]

Comment: As mentioned above, if you added a new tag locally doesn't this mean it isn't pushed to the remote?

Answer (score 3):

In SourceTree, this seems to work:

1. Click the Fetch icon
2. Check "Fetch all tags"
3. Click Ok