# Change naming convention of tags inside a git repository?

Tags: git

I have a git repository which contains a number of tags with the format "v1.2.3-rc-4" which I would like to automatically rename to "1.2.3-rc4". The tags exist in both the local and remote repositories.

I should clarify that the numeric components in the version number should be treated as variables. The above values are simply to demonstrate the format of the tags.

Is there a way to automate this change?

Comment: Check this post to rename tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028649/rename-a-tag-in-git. To automate it write a bash script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To list all tags, I would recommend [`git for-each-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) with the `--shell` option [to eval refs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3847586/6309).
Combine it with a [one-liner to rename/delete a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245862/6309).

```sh
#!/bin/sh

git for-each-ref --shell --format="ref=%(refname:short)" refs/tags | \
while read entry
do

    # assign tag name to $ref variable
    eval "$entry"

    # test if $ref starts with v
    ref2="${ref#v}"
    if [[ "${ref}" != "${ref2}" ]]; then

        # rename/delete tag
        git push origin refs/tags/${ref}:refs/tags/${ref2} :refs/tags/${ref}
        git tag -d ${ref}
    fi

done
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the 3 step approach for a one or a few number of tags. For large number of tags the above script can be modified to use the below 3 steps as an alternative solution.

### Step 1: Identify the commit/object ID of the commit the current tag is pointing to

```
     command: git rev-parse <tag name>
     example: git rev-parse v0.1.0-Demo
     example output: db57b63b77a6bae3e725cbb9025d65fa1eabcde
```

### Step 2: Delete the tag from the repository

```
     command: git tag -d <tag name>
     example: git tag -d v0.1.0-Demo
     example output: Deleted tag 'v0.1.0-Demo' (was abcde)
```

### Step 3: Create a new tag pointing to the same commit id as the old tag was pointing to

```
     command: git tag -a <tag name>  -m "appropriate message" <commit id>
     example: git tag -a v0.1.0-full  -m "renamed from v0.1.0-Demo" db57b63b77a6bae3e725cbb9025d65fa1eabcde
     example output: Nothing or basically <No error>
```

Once the local git is ready with the tag name change, these changes can be pushed back to the origin for others to take these.