# Git: rename tag keeping original date

Tags: git, github, version-control, tags, versioning

In this question [How do you rename a Git tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028649/how-do-you-rename-a-git-tag) instructions are given to rename an old tag.

I'd like to know it these steps will keep the original date in the edited tag in place.

For example, in my `git` repo the `git tag` command shows:

```
v0.1
v1.0.0-beta
```

and Github shows:

[image]

I want to update the old `v0.1` tag to a more descriptive `v1.0.0-alpha` (which also follows the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) guidelines) but I'd also like to keep the original date (*4 Dec 2013*) in place.

Is this possible using the commands given in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5719854/1391441) to the question mentioned above? These would be the commands in my case as I understand:

```
git tag v1.0.0-alpha v0.1
git tag -d v0.1
git push origin :refs/tags/v0.1
git push --tags
```

Comment: If you give a downvote, would you please explain why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you rename a Git tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028649/how-do-you-rename-a-git-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just went ahead and tried, it does keep the date in place.

Comment: The date is derived from the commit to which the tag refers -- hence it's not changed.

Comment: @krlmlr This is not true for annotated tags. If the tag has a description, the date will likely be changed.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro it will "likely" be changed, depending on what?

Comment: @Stevoisiak - Just verified with Github that the tag date is not changed. This worked liked a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In our repository I noticed that one of our older releases had an incorrect version tag. The name was `v.1.28.0` instead of `v1.28.0`. I wanted to correct the issue without somehow messing up the GitHub release.

These are the steps I did to correct it:

1. check out the incorrect tag, e.g. `git checkout v.1.28.0`
2. create a temporary branch, e.g. `git checkout -b release/v1.28.0`
3. push the temporary branch, e.g. `git push -u origin release/v1.28.0`
4. edit the release in GitHub, change the tag name and point it to the temporary branch
5. save the changes on GitHub
6. check out a different branch, e.g. `git checkout develop`
7. remove the temporary branch, e.g. `git branch -d release/v1.28.0`
8. remove the old incorrect tag, e.g. `git tag -d v.1.28.0`