# How to delete the mistakenly case-changed renamed tag in github?

Tags: windows, git, github, git-tag

I had a tag **v1.0.0-RC1** in my Github repo. I wanted to rename it to all lowercase like **v1.0.0-rc1**.
So, I did it from the release edit page https://github.com/username/repo/releases/edit/v1.0.0-RC1.
I found that it created a new tag **v1.0.0-rc1** and it made me having two duplicate tags **v1.0.0-RC1** and **v1.0.0-rc1** in my repo.

The following is how my Github tags page is showing the latest 5 tags. The latest tag is **v1.1.0-rc**. 
The second **v1.1.0-rc1** is my mistaken tag. The last tag is the one I wanted to rename.

```
v1.1.0-rc …
 84da1ca   zip   tar.gz   Notes   Downloads

v1.0.0-rc1 …
Merge branch 'minor'
 2823515   zip   tar.gz

v1.1.0-beta …
 94d9821   zip   tar.gz   Notes   Downloads

v1.0.0 …
 0c052f5   zip   tar.gz   Notes   Downloads

v1.0.0-RC1 …
 1955b7a   zip   tar.gz   Notes   Downloads
```

Here is the result of `git fetch`.

```
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
From https://github.com/username/repo
 * [new tag]         v1.0.0-rc1 -> v1.0.0-rc1
 * [new tag]         v1.1.0-rc  -> v1.1.0-rc
From https://github.com/username/repo
 * [new tag]         v1.0.0-RC1 -> v1.0.0-RC1
```

I want to delete **v1.0.0-rc1**. I know how to delete a remote tag.

```
git tag -d v1.0.0-rc1
git push origin :refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc1
```

But I'm afraid that it could delete the both tag **rc1** and **RC1**. How can I achieve this safely? I'm using [Git for Windows](https://msysgit.github.io/) and it's likely to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I'm afraid that it could delete the both tag rc1 and RC1.

It shouldn't: tags are case-sensitive.

> How can I achieve this safely?

You could [rename your tag locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1028649/1179841) before deleting it, if you really want to be on the safe side (and using a case insensitive OS).
You don't need to do the same on the GitHub side (which does respect the case)

Comment: If I rename my tag locally, e.g, **v1.0.0-RC1** to something else, will it really keep tagging the commit where it was? What I want to do is - (1) rename **v1.0.0-RC1** to **v1.0.0-tmp** (2) delete **v1.0.0-rc1** (3) rename **v1.0.0-tmp** to **v1.0.0-RC1** (4) `git push --tags`. Can I do it safely without breaking the current commit references for each tag ?

Comment: Yes, a tag always reference the same commit when you rename it.

Comment: Unfortunately, tag name are case-insensitive in Windows git bash. `git tag -d v1.0.0-rc1` did delete `v1.0.0-RC1`.

Comment: @Sithu ok, hence the suggestion to rename first.

Comment: @Sithu note that whatever is deleted by mistake would still be referenced in the `git reflog` (http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog), so restoring an improper delete remains easy and accurate.