# Error while importing a Git repository

Tags: git, import

I'm trying to import a Git repository using the command-line. I'm using this [guide](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-a-git-repository-using-the-command-line/)

But I keep running into this error at Step 3:

```
% git push --mirror https://github.com/kbavishi/prads.git
[...]
remote: error: GH002: Sorry, branch or tag names consisting of 40 hex characters are not allowed.
remote: error: Invalid branch or tag name "19f72fa66ffc0ba33f00ba5e5897e109f822e939"
To https://github.com/kbavishi/prads.git
! [remote rejected] 19f72fa66ffc0ba33f00ba5e5897e109f822e939 -> 19f72fa66ffc0ba33f00ba5e5897e109f822e939 (pre-receive hook declined)
[...]
```

Any idea how to fix this? Apologies in advance, I'm a newbie to Git.

I posted a request on Github support, and I received a response asking me to use `git-filter-branch` command to amend the tag, and then try importing the repository again. I couldn't quite figure out how to use that

Answer (score 2):

If, when typing git tag, you see a tag named "`19f72fa66ffc0ba33f00ba5e5897e109f822e939`", you should be able [to rename it easily enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1873932/6309).

```
git tag NEW OLD 
tag -d OLD
```

If it is a branch name (type `git branch`), you should be able to [rename it as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/6309).

```
git branch -m <oldname> <newname>
```

Once this is done, you can mirror push back to your GitHub repo.