# Change naming convention of github release tags

Tags: github, release, github-actions, release-management, github-release

I've joined a project which uses Github actions & releases. Unfortunately, naming convention of release tags changed in the past (probably due to migration from Travis CI).

Until a certain point of time, the tags were like this (not sure why the numbers were so high):

```
v1018.0.0
v1018.1.0
v1020.0.0
v1024.0.0
```

Then someone switched to semantic versioning (which is great btw):

```
v2.5.1
v3.0.0
v3.1.0
v3.1.1
```

Our CI/CD works just fine, but we have some issues:

- We use Release Drafter. It creates a description for a new release which should consist of all PRs since the previous release. But now it compares current state of our master branch **not** with the **latest** tag (v3.1.1), but with a tag with **the highest major number** (v1024.0.0). Which means the draft always consists of 100+ PRs merged since one year ago. So we end up deleting the whole release description, because noone has time to analyse that.
- It's messy. Github always suggests v1024 as the newest version: when creating new releases, when switching between tags and so on.

My two questions are:

- Is there any safe way to update names of all old tags? F.e. change v1024.0.0 into v0.1024.0. Doesn't have to be automatic. Keep in mind it should update the tagnames only, I don't want to change release date, assets etc. I think that editing a release using Github UI would in fact create a new tag based on master (and maybe even release it to live server?)
- If not, is there any way to tell Release Drafter that it should use the **latest** tag instead of the **highest** one?

Answer (score -1):

Well a little googling would tell you many things :)

- [How do you rename a Git tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028649/how-do-you-rename-a-git-tag)
- https://gist.github.com/rponte/fdc0724dd984088606b0

Yes you can update tags (see first link)
Yes you can get the latest tag - see second link.

Comment: First link: yeah, but wouldn't deleting 100 old tags and adding 100 new tags trigger 100 releases through github actions (affecting production)?

Second link: I don't know how it could help with Release Drafter? But after even more research I think this is simply not possible - unless I introduce another breaking tag: https://github.com/release-drafter/release-drafter/blob/349214e6b3b889d8b333c012cc61a1f1753baf40/lib/releases.js#L8